# Add openssl library into my project, got errors 'openssl/ossl_typ.h' file not found

Tags: c, openssl

I installed openssl-1.1.0f and added the library into my source code.

```
myProject (Folder)
- myApp (Folder)
  - myApp.c
- openssl-1.1.0f (Folder)
```

In my source code myApp.c, I added below:

```
#include "../openssl-1.1.0f/include/openssl/rand.h"
#include "../openssl-1.1.0f/include/openssl/ssl.h"
```

And I compiled.

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -static -o myApp myApp.c -L../openssl/openssl-1.1.0f/ -lssl -lcrypto -I../openssl/openssl-1.1.0f/include
```

I got the errors.

```
../../openssl-1.1.0f/include/openssl/rand.h:14:11 fatal error 'openssl/ossl_typ.h' file not found
```

But there is ossl_typ.h file in openssl-1.1.0f/include/openssl.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You must run `Configure` to generate some installation specific files. Did you do so?

Comment: I did it- configure, Make and make install by INSTALL guide. And I didn't change anything in 'openssl-1.1.0f' folder.

Answer (score 1):

You've included the files incorrectly. You need to tell the compiler where the include files are for openssl, with the `-I` option.

Currently you're telling it that to look in "../openssl/openssl-1.1.0f/include/" which is wrong as that folder doesn't exist. According to the folder layout it should be "-I../openssl-1.1.0f/include/". You don't then need to specify the full path when you include the files as the compiler will be able to see them.

```
#include "openssl/rand.h"
#include "openssl/ssl.h"
```

Inside those files it's including "openssl/ossl_typ.h" which it'll now be able to find if you tell it the right place to look.

Comment: That is 'openssl-1.1.0f' folder which I download and installed. I don't want to change openssl open source folder.

Comment: You're not changing the folder, you're putting the correct path in. I've altered my answer to hopefully make that more clear?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best thing you can do, as the `openssl-1.1.0f` package uses an `include` directory, to add

```
CFLAGS += "-I<pathToOpenSSlParentDir>/openssl-1.1.0f/include"
```

to your `Makefile`, and then

```
...
#include <openssl/rand.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
...
```

in the files you are going to compile.  Or you can better install your openssl in your system as default, and then everything will work as expected.

The reason of my last paragraph is that, if you compile openssl to shared libraries, then you'll have to add `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:<pathToOpenSSlParentDir>/openssl-1.1.0f/build` or something similar, for the runtime to be able to locate them at runtime.  You can avoid this issue forcing to link with static linking, but at the expense of larger executable and more than one instance of the library loaded in memory at runtime.